# Biblatex show same author again instead of "-"

Tags: latex, bibtex

I want to show "Liu, Bing" again also for the second reference. How can I do this? I'm using Biblatex with the following setup:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
```

and

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
dashed=false
```

to your biblatex package options